# Excel fill handle function with different sheets

Tags: excel

This might seem lame to some of you but please can you help me? How do you get an equation in Excel to be able to refer to different sheets when using the "fill handle"? For Eg. when I pull down on the fill handler the value of the same cell in multiple sheets must be selected (sheet1 cell A1, sheet2 cell A1; sheet3 cell A3;...).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your sheet names are `Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, ...` enter the following formula in `Row 1`:

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet" & ROW() & "'!$A$1")
```

This will give you `Cell A1` values of all sheets.

If your formula in entered in any other row apart from 1, then change the formula as `=INDIRECT("'Sheet" & ROW()-r-1 & "'!$A$1")` where r is starting row number. For example if your formula starts from Row 6 then formula will be `=INDIRECT("'Sheet" & ROW()-5 & "'!$A$10")`

**EDIT :** As per comment

Assuming you are entering formula in first row, your formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK('7'!$E$41)=TRUE,0,LARGE('7'!$E$41:$E$43,1))
```

should be

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("'" & ROW()+6 & "'!$E$41"))=TRUE,0,LARGE(INDIRECT("'" & ROW()+6 & "'!$E$41:$E$43"),1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think my explanation on the matter might be a bit vague. Or I might not have enough experience with programming to fully understand your answer. I want to type in the equation in the formula bar in excel and then copy the formula to other cells in the same sheet using data of other sheets in the same document. Eg. of a formula I am using: =IF(ISBLANK('7'!$E$41)=TRUE,0,LARGE('7'!$E$41:$E$43,1)) .....I want the 7 to change to an 8 and so forth when I use the fill handler (dragging the cell down).

Answer (score 1):

Just click Shift and select all other worksheets and do selection or filling as required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I use it I am able to extract data from many sheets in one formula. So it works, just not for my problem.      I want to type in the equation in the formula bar in excel and then copy the formula to other cells in the same sheet using data of other sheets in the same document. Eg. of a formula I am using: =IF(ISBLANK('7'!$E$41)=TRUE,0,LARGE('7'!$E$41:$E$43,1)) .....I want the 7 to change to an 8 and so forth when I use the fill handler (dragging the cell down).